# attach event to child elements, code improvements and better maintenability

Tags: jquery

I have a form, that I identify with the attribute `form[data-role="party-form"]`.

I need to attach logic to its N elements `[data-role="element1...N"]` and I've done it this way:

```
$('form[data-role="party-form"] [data-role="element1"]').change(function(e){
       var el = $(e.target);
       var form = el.parents('form[data-role="party-form"]');
       // custom logic for element 1 accessing other form elements
}

// ...

$('form[data-role="party-form"] [data-role="elementN"]').change(function(e){
       var el = $(e.target);
       var form = el.parents('form[data-role="party-form"]');
       // custom logic for element N accessing other form elements
}
```

I don't like this code a lot, as there is lots of repetition (parent selector and logic to get the parent form)

I was thinking about refactoring into a "onchange" listener to "input" elements of the form (and a `switch` on the clicked element), or a more object-oriented approach, but - before I continue - anyone has in mind a better way to implement this ?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery attribute ^ selector,it will match all element which attribute start width something:

```
$('form[data-role="party-form"] [data-role^="element"]').change(function(e){
       var el = $(e.target);
       var form = el.parents('form[data-role="party-form"]');
       var index = form.attr("data-role").replace("element","");
       // custom logic for element [index] 
}
```

Comment: thanks. the "element" prefix is just there for question clarity, in practice I have different naming. I could actually add a common attribute to all the fields, or just get all the "input,select" of the form, but I was wondering what were other alternatives